# VBA run loop until number of instances is reached

Tags: vba, excel, loops, count

I need to run a macro that will fix the years in an excel sheet. The year to the left of "Nov - Jan" is 2010 but I add + 1 to make it 2011. The loop then needs to find the next "Nov_Jan" and do the same 2011 + 1 = 2012. To stop the loop I know I need to count the number of instance of "Nov-Jan" and run it as many instances. So there are only 4 "Nov-Jan", run the loop only 4 times. The code below runs the loop within the same cell and doesn't continue to look for the next "Nov-Jan". I can't figure out why. I have an image to show I need to go from "Before" -> "After", but my code goes from "Before" -> "What I Have".

```
Dim iCount As Integer 
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

iCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "Nov - Jan")

Cells.Find(what:="Nov - Jan", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Do Until i > iCount
    i = i + 1

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + 1

    Cells.Find(what:="Nov - Jan", after:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Loop
```

I need to go from "Before" -> "After", but my code goes from "Before" -> "What I Have"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple code:

```
Sub loops()
Dim c as range
'Change the "Sheet2" reference to your sheet name.
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B")
    Set c = .Find("Nov - Jan", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Offset(, -1) = c.Offset(, -1) + 1
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

When using the find method it has a built in next function.  It can also be assigned to a range that then can be manipulated to do what is needed.

See [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx) for more information.

In your code you are looping, but the loop resets the search each time, therefore it only finds the first each time.

Comment: ... wish I'de seen this before writing the same darn thing!

Comment: @Jeeped I think you out number me 2 to 1 on getting your answer in before I can.

Comment: @ScottCraner you are a life saver! Thank you so much!

Comment: @code3dgyt3ch please consider marking as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.